# Exception in Application start method

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to load the FXML file and show it as an application window, but i get an exception. The FXML file was created by the FXML Scene Builder.

Sup.java file:

```
package sup;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;


public class Sup extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));



        primaryStage.setTitle("Sup");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);        
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

sample.fxml file:

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<GridPane fx:controller="sup.Controller"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="5"> 

    <Text text="Sup"
        GridPane.rowIndex="0"
        GridPane.columnSpan="2"
        GridPane.halignment="CENTER"/>

    <Label text="First Name:"
        GridPane.rowIndex="1"
        GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>

    <TextField
        GridPane.columnIndex="1"
        GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>

    <Button text="Say Sup!"
        GridPane.rowIndex="2"
        GridPane.columnIndex="1"
        GridPane.halignment="RIGHT"/>

</GridPane>
```

screenshot of structure:

[image]

error message:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at sup.Sup.start(Sup.java:34)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application sup.Sup
```

Answer (score 3):

The root cause of the exception you are getting is a `NullPointerException` with the detail message "Location is required.".

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
```

I am not going to guide you how to read stack traces, please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/4464702) instead.

You are getting the "location is required" error because you are passing `null` into the [`FXMLLoader.load()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load-java.net.URL-) method. The `null` value must obviously come from the [`getResource()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) call. From the [`Class.getResource()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) documentation:

> [...]
>
> **Returns:**
>   A [`URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) object or `null` if no resource with this name is found
>
> [...]

So the reason why you are getting the exception has to be that the resource with the given name cannot be found.

Please validate the following:

- If you are using the standard **eclipse project layout**: Make sure you placed the `sample.fxml` into the same directory as the `Sup.java` file
- If you are using a **maven-like directory structure** where there are different directories for resources and sources, make sure the `sample.fxml` is in the resource folder and in the same directory like the source file.

  Example: Your source file `Sup.java` is placed in `src/main/java/com/example/Sup.java`. Place the `sample.fxml` file into `src/main/resources/com/example/sample.fxml`.
- If you are using eclipse, clean and rebuild your project. Build tools have similar alternatives (or just delete the `build`/`out` directory)